# How to deal with failed migrations during deployment in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, deployment, backend, rails-migrations

To evolve a DB schema over time we need to do DB migrations. Rails provide us with great functionality to do that. As we know, each migration in Rails is wrapped in a DDL transaction (at least for Postgres). It means that if some migration is failed in halfway then all changes related to this migration will be rolled back. But, I've noticed that if we have more than one migration and one of them fails then previous migrations will not have been rolled back. And it is a problem in terms of production deployment since a new portion of migrations can be done partially.

Let's imagine we have 5 new migrations that we want to deploy into production.

```
migration_1.rb
migration_2.rb
migration_3.rb
migration_4.rb
migration_5.rb
```

If an error occurs for example on `migration_4.rb` then all previous migrations (`migration_1.rb`, `migration_2.rb`, `migration_3.rb`) will not have been rolled back.

How should I handle this situation?

I have an idea to cancel code deployment and rollback previous migrations by something like this

```bash
rails db:rollback STEP=n # n - number of migrations that managed to pass successfully
```

But then I have another question - what if an error occurs during rolling back?

Comment: IMO, the easiest way to avoid problems of migrations is to make your schema backward compatible and deploy them separately from the code changes (e.g. deploy removal of model first, then the migration to drop the table, or add a new column first, then deploy the related change). In this case, if a migration fails and the code rolled back, the app runs without any problem. Would it be something that you can apply?

Comment: You fix migration 4 and deploy again.  The first three are successful, why would your want to roll them back?

Comment: @dbugger Here is an example. If I leave old code on the production then some functionality can become broken since one of the first three migrations can contain renaming a column. So I would like to revert the first three migrations to leave the old column name and not break anything.

Comment: @dbugger On the other hand, I can deploy new code anyway despite some broken migrations but then functionality that depends on undone migrations will be broken till I fix and deploy those migrations.

Comment: In both cases, users will notice that something went wrong. So, I'm interested in how to manage such situations to make users not notice that something happened.

Comment: This why you have a QA environment to test your deployments and verify that your migrations work as expected and fix them when they don't.  Much simpler than building some mechanism to rollback successful migrations.

Comment: @dbugger yes, we have development and staging environments and it is a great idea. But this is not what I’m asking about)

Comment: As I said -- your time would be better spent elsewhere.

Comment: "some functionality can become broken since one of the first three migrations can contain renaming a column" Then your app will be broken even if everything succeeds. Because during the deploy the app will be briefly running (depending on your deploy process) old code on new database or new code on old database. https://github.com/ankane/strong_migrations will notify if you're doing something dangerous in your migrations (like rename) that should be split to multiple deploys.

Answer (score 2):

The best practice I'd recommend: **Only have one migration per deploy**. Migrations run in a transaction, so if a single one fails, no harm done, assuming the deploy as a whole fails with it (so you don't end up deploying code changes that rely on the failed migration).

But if one succeeds and the next one fails, your database will end up in a state that you didn't intend, and you will have to manually roll back.

If your multiple migrations are related to each other and need to be deployed as one, just refactor them into a single migration file. If they belong to separate features that can be deployed individually, do that instead.

Regarding rollback failures - your migrations should *always* be able to roll back, and this should be part of your development process. If you migrate data, make sure to migrate it back in the `down` version, for example.

An easy way to test this is using `db:migrate:redo` locally. It's good practice to always to that before committing a migration.

Comment: It sounds interesting, but I can't integrate that approach into my project now. But anyway thank you for your thoughts.